# How 2get only non-stop flights in BargainFinderMax (RESTmode) by using 'FlightStopsAsConnections', 'MaxStopsQuantity', or 'DirectFlightsOnly' in input

Tags: c#, sabre

I am using Sabre BargainFinderMax (BFM) call to get flight availability.  In the input, I must provide a flag to get only 'non-stop' flights.  What node/property/value should be used to achieve this, if possible.  Again, ONLY 'non-stop' must be returned!
thanks in advance!

I tried using DirectFlightsOnly=true, but got same response when the node was not included in the RQ.

"DirectFlightsOnly" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },

Comment: "How 2get" is hardly the "processional language" that is expected here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for the API you are using. Please contact the company you for the service you are using and ask them for technical details about the service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this element:

```
<TravelPreferences>
<FlightTypePref MaxConnections="0"/>
```

That would return only flights with no connections. I'm not familiar with the element you mentioned.

Comment: I found where to put the node, and BFM is indeed returning 'non-stop' flights! Tx